# Error with C++ template function in vector sort

Tags: c++, templates

I want to use a template function for sorting a vector of a class but I got compilation error. The error is due to template. It compiles when I use a class instead of template.

```
class Person
{
    private:
      int ssn;
      string name;

    public:
      Person() {};
      Person(int s, string na) { ssn = s; name = na; }
      const int getSSN() { return ssn; }

      friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Person& per) {
          out << per.ssn << "  " << per.name;
      }
};

template <typename T> 
bool myfunction(T i, T j) { return (i.getSSN() < j.getSSN()); }
// it complies fine when I use 
// bool myfunction(Person i, Person j) { return (i.getSSN() < j.getSSN()); }

int main()
{
    ifstream in("personal.dat");
    string st;
    vector<Person> *vect = new vector<Person>;
    int ssn;
    string name;
    while(in >> ssn >> name) {
            Person per(ssn, name);
            vect->push_back(per);
    }
    in.close();

    sort(vect->begin(), vect->end(), myfunction);
    for(int i=0; i<vect->size(); i++) cout << vect->at(i) << endl;
}
```

Compilation errors:

```
read.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
read.cxx:41:45: error: no matching function for call to  ‘sort(std::vector<Person>::
iterator, std::vector<Person>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
sort(vect->begin(), vect->end(), myfunction);

read.cxx:41:45: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/algorithm:62:0,
         from read.cxx:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_algo.h:5438:5: note: template<class _RAIter> 
void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first,
_RandomAccessIterator __last)
.................
.................
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `myFunction` is a template so its template parameter needs to be specified.

Comment: why don't you use a lambda instead?

Comment: BTW, all *const references* are missing :/

Answer (score 3):

You should tell it the type of elements you want to compare:

```
sort(begin, end, myfunction<Person>);
```

Comment: Here, I showed only one class which I want to sort. But in my actual code, there are more than one class and I want to write a generic code to sort them inside another class.

Comment: The syntax in this answer is slightly wrong: missing `()`

Comment: @manojg: A _function_ can't do that, but a _functionoid_ can: you'll have to convert the template function to a nontemplate class that has a template function call operator.

Comment: @manojg: However, I note that it only works for classes that have a `.getSSN()` member, so I'm not sure why it's templated.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: I am using the same sort function in the base class as well as it derived classes. So, all have .getSSN() method.

Comment: @manojg: So the parameter type should be `const base&` then, and `.getSSN()` should be virtual.

Answer (score 2):

`myfunction` is a function template that represents an infinite overload set. For the compiler to resolve which overload you want you need to provide the template parameters. In this case you want a `Person` comparision function:

```c++
std::sort(vect->begin(), vect->end(), myfunction<Person>);
```

Alternatively, you can provide a lambda expression which forwards the parameters to `myfunction`:

```c++
std::sort(vect->begin(), vect->end(),
[&] (Person const& lhs, Person const& rhs) { return myfunction(lhs, rhs); });
```

Moreover, you are needlessly allocating a `std::vector` dynamically. The point of a vector is to dispense with the manual memory management of dynamic C-style arrays. Just allocate statically and instead of using the `->` operator use `.`:

```c++
std::vector<Person> vect;
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to use the "myfunction" for a template class without specifying the class name so that I can use the same implementation of the "sort" for other classes too?

Comment: @manojg Yes, create a class with an overloaded `operator()` that does the comparison. Create overloads for different classes if needed. Then just pass an instance of that class as the comparator functor.

Comment: Thanks, sounds better way to do this. I will try it.

Answer (score -2):

```
//Actually, it was simple. I used following line in small test code it works fine.

//sort(fileVector->begin(), fileVector->end(), myfunction<T>);

//However, in my actual code, it crashes with Segmentation fault (core dumped). I am 
//looking on this.

template <class T>
bool myfunction(T i, T j) { return (i.getSSN() < j.getSSN()); }

template <class T>
void sortt(vector<T> *vect)
{
    sort(vect->begin(), vect->end(), myfunction<T>);
}


int main()
{
   ..............
   ..............
   sortt(vect);
}
```

Comment: That can't compile - `T` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it is template <class T> at the top, I put it in corrected form.

Comment: `std::sort()`'s comparator should not mutate its arguments and for that reason its parameters should take references to `const`, not by value arguments.